# Subsetting a column in data frame of class chron by a vector of dates

Tags: r, subset, chron

I have a dataframe like the one given by:

```
x <- c(1:6)
y <- c("06/01/13 16:00:00",
       "06/01/13 16:00:00", 
       "06/03/13 20:00:00",
       "06/03/13 20:00:00",
       "06/07/13 20:00:00", 
       "06/08/13 20:00:00")
dfrm <- data.frame(x,y)
dfrm
   x             y
  1 06/01/13 16:00:00
  2 06/01/13 16:00:00
  3 06/03/13 20:00:00
  4 06/03/13 20:00:00
  5 06/07/13 20:00:00
  6 06/08/13 20:00:00
```

I want to make y a chron object:

```
dfrm$y <- as.chron(dfrm$y, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
```

Then I have a vector of dates:

```
intensives <- c("06/01/13", "06/07/13")
```

Then I want to subset the data frame "dfrm" by the dates in the "intensives" vector.
What I would do it would something like:

```
subset(dfrm, y==dates(intensives))
```

or

```
subset(dfrm, y %in% dates(intensives))
```

but both give me a null result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:In most person's setups where stringAsFactors=TRUE that conversion to chron would have failed. They would need to do this:

```
dfrm$y <- as.chron(as.character(dfrm$y), "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
```

date-objects are not chron-objects, but chron objects can be coerced with the `dates` function

```
 subset(dfrm, dates(y) %in% dates(intensives))
  x                   y
1 1 (06/01/13 16:00:00)
2 2 (06/01/13 16:00:00)
5 5 (06/07/13 20:00:00)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're comparing datetimes to dates.

Do `subset(dfrm, dates(y) %in% dates(intensives))` instead.

You first subset using `==` will never work, regardless of data type.